# Функция должна удалить из массива все простые числа и вернуть указатель на новый массив

Tags: c++, указатели, динамические-массивы

Написать функцию, которая получает указатель на массив и его размер. Функция должна удалить из массива все простые числа и вернуть указатель на новый массив.
Почему программа выводит фигню? Если можно прокомментируйте ошибки, пожалуйста.

```
#include<iostream>
#include <cmath>
using namespace std;

int prostae_chislo(int n){
    int f = 1;
    if ((n==2)||(n==3))
        f=1;
    else{
     for (int i = 2; i < floor(sqrt(n)); i++)
          if (n % i == 0)
          {
              f = 0;
              break;
          }
    }
     return (f && (n != 1));
}

int* proverca(int* A, int size){
    int i,j,*B;
    int k=0;
    for (i=0; i<size; i++){
        if ( prostae_chislo(A[i]) == 1);
        k++;
    }
    B=new int [k];
    j=-1;
    for (i=0; i<size; i++)
        if (prostae_chislo(A[i]) == 0)
            B[j++]=A[i];
    for(int j = 0; j < k; j++)
        cout << B[j] << " ";
    delete [] A;
    return B;
}

int main()
{
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "rus");
    int size;
    cout << "Введите размер массива: ";
    cin >> size;
    int* A = new int[size];
    cout << "Заполните массив: ";
    for(int i = 0; i<size; i++)
        cin >> A[i];
    int* res = proverca(A, size);
    cout <<" "<< res << endl;
    delete []A;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Что выводит программа?

Comment: Одна из ошибок - Вы дважды вызываете delete для А. Один раз в главной функции, второй - в proverca. При этом память выделенная под В течёт, тк нигде не освобождается

Comment: @Cerbo сразу два больших восьмизначных числа и четыре нуля если size = 6

Comment: j=-1; B[j++]=A[i];  здесь вы первый раз обращаетесь по индексу -1. Помимо всего прочего неверно работает prostae_chislo, возвращает 1 для значения 4. В общем ошибка на ошибке

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Исправил большую часть очевидных ошибок. Настоятельно рекомендую первым делом проанализировать их и стараться писать более осмысленно код и аккуратно.

Из грубых ошибок:

1) Обратите внимание на корректность выделения и освобождения памяти

2) Следите за обращением к массивам - вы обращались по несуществующему индексу -1

Остальное:

3) Сигнатура функции bool prostae_chislo(int n) очевидно должна возвращать булев тип. Возвращение int и проверка результата на 1 неочевидна

4) Старайтесь объявлять переменные там, где вы их используете. Не скапливайти их все в начале функции

```
#include<iostream>
#include <cmath>
using namespace std;

bool prostae_chislo(int n){
    bool result(true);

    if ((n==2)||(n==3))
        result = true;
    else{
        for (int i = 2; i <= floor(sqrt(n)); ++i)
            if (n % i == 0)
            {
                result = false;
                break;
            }
    }
    return (result && (n != 1));
}

int* proverca(int* A, int size){

    int count = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < size; ++i){
        if (!prostae_chislo(A[i]))
            ++count;
    }

    int* B = new int[count];

    int j = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < size; ++i)
        if (!prostae_chislo(A[i]))
            B[j++] = A[i];

    for(int j = 0; j < count; j++)
        cout << B[j] << " ";
    return B;
}

int main()
{
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "rus");
    int size;
    cout << "Введите размер массива: ";
    cin >> size;
    int* A = new int[size];
    cout << "Заполните массив: ";
    for(int i = 0; i<size; i++)
        cin >> A[i];
    int* res = proverca(A, size);

    delete []A;
    delete []res;
    return 0;
}
```

Result:

```
Введите размер массива: 5
Заполните массив: 2
3
4
5
6
4 6
```

Comment: ТС просила прокоментировать ошибки, вы же просто сделали работу на нее.